# How to listen for real-time updates on a list of documents in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I'm using `get()`, to grab some documents from Firestore. This is my code:

```
val ids = getIds()
val tasks: MutableList<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> = mutableListOf()
for (id in ids) {
    tasks.add(collRef.document(id).get())
}
Tasks.whenAllSuccess<DocumentSnapshot>(tasks).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (doc in task.result!!) {
            Log.d("TAG", doc.getString("name"))
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine. `getIds()` returns a list of 25 Ids, so the result in the **Logcat** is 25 names. But this code only gets the data once, meaning that if something is added, I don't get it unless I reload the activity. I read about [listen to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection), but this meant to be used with a query. I tried:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess<DocumentSnapshot>(tasks).addSnapshotListener()
```

But Android Studio is complaining with:

```
Unresolved reference: addSnapshotListener
```

How can I listen for real-time updates for all 25 documents? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tasks.whenAllSuccess()` returns a new Task object that completes when all the other tasks complete.  That's not going to work here at all, since listeners don't really ever "complete".  If you're trying to use listeners instead of a one-time fetch with `get()`, you're going to need to set up a listener **on each individual document reference** as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#kotlin+ktx).

```
for (id in ids) {
    collRef.document(id).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e -> 
        // handle the updates here
    }
}
```

There is no "bulk listen" operation.  Each reference needs a listener attached.  You can pass the same [EventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/EventListener) object to each one, if you want, instead of creating a new object for each one.

Don't forget to remove the listeners when you are done.

Comment: Thank you Doug for your answer. I thought about this but isn't it costly or bad practice to attach so many listeners for each and every document? In my case there 25, but if I have more than 50?

Comment: The only cost is the document reads required to get the initial data and all the updates.  It's not a problem to have lots of listeners.

Comment: If that's not a problem I will go ahead and use the listeners. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so skilled in Kotlin but when i need to listen to a collection in Java, first i create a reference to the collection of documents and then i add SnapshotListener to the collection like this

```
CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("MyCollection");
    ref.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@androidx.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @androidx.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            //Here use queryDocumentSnapshot to retrieve every document data
        }
    });
```

Using **queryDocumentSnapshots** you can retrieve realtime updates to the colletion

You can also use a Query to select which documents you need to listen for

Comment: Thanks but that's not my case. I'm not listening to a collection or a Query. I just have a list of `DocumentSnapshot` that I pass to `whenAllSuccess`. For each and every document I need real-time updates.

Comment: Ok the only solution that comes in my mind is to create a **for{}** Cycle and addSnapshotListener for every document, but I'm not sure is what you're looking for